# spirit x3: locally defined rule definition must have an attribute attached?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

Simple x3 code cannot compile because nothing is attached to the 2nd ruleTest or the whole parser. Even if we put `x3::omit[ruleTest]` around the second `ruleTest` it still cannot compile.

```
void Test(std::string const& str) {
    auto const ruleTest = x3::rule<struct _, std::string>{} =
        *(x3::char_ - ' ')[([](auto& ctx){x3::_val(ctx)+='x';})];
    x3::parse(boost::begin(str), boost::end(str), 
        ruleTest[([](auto& ctx){std::cout<<x3::_attr(ctx)<<std::endl;})] >>
        ' ' >>
        ruleTest
    );
}
```

Only when we attach a lambda or an attribute to x3::parse or define ruleTest globally with BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE could solve the problem.

```
void Test(std::string const& str) {
    auto const ruleTest = x3::rule<struct _, std::string>{} =
        *(x3::char_ - ' ')[([](auto& ctx){x3::_val(ctx)+='x';})];
    std::string attr;
    x3::parse(boost::begin(str), boost::end(str), 
        ruleTest[([](auto& ctx){std::cout<<x3::_attr(ctx)<<std::endl;})] >>
        ' ' >>
        ruleTest, attr);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux of the error appears to be

```
test.cpp|9 col 59| error: no match for ‘operator+=’ (operand types are ‘boost::spirit::x3::unused_type’ and ‘char’)
```

This is because the compiler sees the actual type of the bound attribute (none) is `x3::unused_type` and therefore the semantic action doesn't compile.

I'm not even sure how you would want it work since you cannot update characters to `'x'` in an attribute that doesn't exist.

Here's a proposed "fix":

```
struct { 
    void operator()(std::string& s, char c) const { s += c; }
    void operator()(...)                    const { }
} ll;

auto const ruleTest 
    = x3::rule<struct _, std::string>{} 
    = *(x3::char_ - ' ') [([ll](auto& ctx){ ll(x3::_val(ctx), 'x');})]
    ;
```

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f3ca34606805e46)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void Test(std::string const& str) {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    struct { 
        void operator()(std::string& s, char c) const { s += c; }
        void operator()(...)                    const { }
    } ll;

    auto const ruleTest 
        = x3::rule<struct _, std::string>{} 
        = *(x3::char_ - ' ') [([ll](auto& ctx){ ll(x3::_val(ctx), 'x');})]
        ;

    //std::string attr;
    auto f = begin(str), l = end(str);
    bool ok = x3::parse(f, l, 
            ruleTest [([](auto& ctx){std::cout<<x3::_attr(ctx)<<std::endl;})] 
            >> ' ' >> ruleTest);

    if (ok)     std::cout << "Parse success\n";
    else        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    if (f != l) std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}

int main() {
    Test("abc def");
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks. But why does globally defined rule does not have this issue?

Comment: I'm not actually too sure myself. Clearly the DEFINE/DECLARE macros have some potential for type-firewalling, but I'm not too sure how it is that the compiler sees through the mechanism if it's local. Come to think of it, I don't think `DECLARE` assigns to the `rule<>` instance, leaving a "stub" that uses the specialization of `parse_rule<>`. This would then "force" the attribute type. Whereas, once a definition is assigned it will not use the `parse_rule<>` method [...]. Need to study more on it one day.